# Simplifying the case statement

Tags: sql, case

Below is my current update statement using `CASE`.

```
UPDATE A
SET OAP.GradeRange = 
        CASE WHEN (ABS(CAST(A.GRADE_FROM AS INT) - CAST(A.GRADE AS INT))) > 1 THEN 'Y'  
        ELSE 'N' END  
FROM   dbo.Table A
```

How do I add an extra filter below into the `CASE` above?

```
where (grade_from <> 13 and GRADE <> 15)
OR (grade_from <> 15 and GRADE <> 13)
```

I am trying this way:

```
 UPDATE A
    SET OAP.GradeRange = 
            CASE WHEN (ABS(CAST(A.GRADE_FROM AS INT) - CAST(A.GRADE AS INT))) AND (grade_from <> 13 and GRADE <> 15) OR (grade_from <> 15 and GRADE <> 13) > 1 THEN 'Y'  
            ELSE 'N' END  
    FROM   dbo.Table A
```

Please advice if there is any better way to write it. Thanks.

Comment: you're probably going to need brackets around your or/and condition inside the case (after the cast stuff) if you want it to work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

I think **> 1 (Greater than 1)** should be come after the first condition.

```
UPDATE A
    SET OAP.GradeRange = 
            CASE WHEN (ABS(CAST(A.GRADE_FROM AS INT) - CAST(A.GRADE AS INT)) > 1) AND ((grade_from NOT IN ('13','15')) OR (GRADE NOT IN ('13','15')))  THEN 'Y'  
            ELSE 'N' END  
    FROM   dbo.Table A
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `case` is missing an extra set of parentheses, so it is not doing what you want:

```
 UPDATE A
    SET OAP.GradeRange = 
            CASE WHEN (ABS(CAST(A.GRADE_FROM AS INT) - CAST(A.GRADE AS INT))) AND
                      ((grade_from <> 13 and GRADE <> 15) OR (grade_from <> 15 and GRADE <> 13) > 1)
                 THEN 'Y'  
                 ELSE 'N' END  
    FROM   dbo.Table A;
```